# Background stops before the bottom of the div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have an issue with the background of my banner where the background stops before the bottom of the div. As a results there is a big white space at the bottom.

This is a responsive website and the issue only happens after the screen size goes below 1250px (just resize your browser and you will see it).

I have tried tweaking the HTML/CSS in using firebug as much as I could (adding clearfixes ect) but nothing I tried had any results.

This is how it looks at full size, and how it should look:
[image]

This is how it looks when under 1250px with the unwanted space under it:
[image]

[This is the website.](http://blog.ekarda.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background image height is short, you need to modify your `.slider1` class as

```
.slider1 {
   background: url("../images/banner-background-01.jpg") repeat-x scroll center 100% transparent;
   /* Rest of the styles goes here */
}
```

Also, as you commented, you can also try using `background-size` property with the `y` parameter that means the vertical size set to `100%`

Comment: That almost fixed it! It now covers the bottom but not the top part. The white intro text is no longer covered

Comment: @ronnz did you set the background size to `100%`? like `background-size: 100%;` am having a big screen so not able to reproduce your issue clearly

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `repeat-x` from the background property for `.slider1`. That should cause the background image to repeat in both x and y which is the default.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more helpful if you had posted some code as well, but probably the quickest way to solve your issue would be to add the following CSS:

```
.slider1 {
     background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```